# How to search in Arrays and return from a method?

Tags: java, arrays, function

I have to write a program that will  fill up the array with random numbers between 1 and 100. The user will input the size of the array. Fill the array up. Then the user will input the number they are looking for and the program will return where that number is located in the array, if it is not in the array, return the -1. Continue doing this until the use enters -1.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter row size");
    int row = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter column size");
    int column = kb.nextInt();

    int [][] Array = new int [row][column];

    System.out.println();
    for ( int r = 0; r < Array.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < Array[r].length ; c++)
        {
            Array [r][c] = (int) (Math.random()*99+1);
            System.out.print(Array[r][c]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println("Please input a number to look for or enter \"-1\" to stop ");
    int find = kb.nextInt();

    findValue (Array, find);

}
    public static int findValue (int [][] Array, int find)
    {
        if (find !=-1)
            {
                for ( int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < Array[x].length ; y++)
                    {
                        if (Array[x][y] == find)
                        {       
                            System.out.println("The number is located in the "+ (x+1) + " row, and the " + (y+1) + " column");
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        }   
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to return "-1" if the number that the user asked for is not in the Array.. Also, I do not know how to keep asking "Please input a number..." and stop when user inputs "-1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, just a few details missing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter row size");
    int row = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter column size");
    int column = kb.nextInt();

    int[][] Array = new int[row][column];

    System.out.println();
    for (int r = 0; r < Array.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < Array[r].length; c++) {
            Array[r][c] = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);
            System.out.print(Array[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    int find;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please input a number to look for or enter \"-1\" to stop ");
        find = kb.nextInt();

        if (find != -1) {

            int[] coordinates = findValue(Array, find);

            if (coordinates[0] == -1 && coordinates[1] == -1) {
                System.out.println("The number could not be found");                    
            } else {
                System.out.println("The number is located in the " + (coordinates[0]) + " row, and the " + (coordinates[1]) + " column");
            }
        }

    } while (find != -1);
}

public static int[] findValue(int[][] Array, int find) {

    int[] coordinates = new int[2];

    coordinates[0] = -1;
    coordinates[1] = -1;

    for (int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Array[x].length; y++) {
            if (Array[x][y] == find) {

                coordinates[0] = x + 1;
                coordinates[1] = y + 1;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return coordinates;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain to me what does it mean when you write "return 1"?

Comment: As you said you wanted to return -1 when the number is not found, the method "findValue" must return an integer. In case of success, I chose to return 1. You can replace 1 with any other number though since it's not used. You can even change the method to "public static void .. " and return nothing. I just tried to follow your requirements, it's really up to you :)

Comment: Oh ok! But where does that "-1" go? I do not understand how can it be used. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with it. If your idea was printing it, you can replace the message "The number could not be found" by "-1". If you don't need it for anything just remove the statements and make the method return void.

Comment: OP asks to return the position of the integer in the array. Here, you return 1 when found. You have to return an integer  array with the values and return an array with -1 when not found.

Comment: You're right, I misread it. I'll update the code in a second.

Comment: Ok Mlaura, try it out and feel free to ask if there is anything you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you so much! and I didn't write the steps, it is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Note: the way `return` works is that your function "gives" a value to wherever you call it. For example, in my code, the function returns an integer array and you can assign it to a variable using

```
int[] positionInArray = findValue(Array, find);
```

Part 1: returning -1

All you have to do is `return` after finding the value in the array:

```
if (Array[x][y] == find){
    return {x,y}
}
```

However, since you are using a 2D array (Why? It doesn't specify in the prompt.) you will have to change the return value of your function to `int[]` so you can return both coordinates.

```
public static int[] findValue (int [][] Array, int find)
```

Then, if you reach the end of the `for` loops, it implies that a match wasn't found, so add a return statement at the end (your IDE should complain about this: you declare a return type of `int` but never return anything):

```
for ( int x = 0; x < Array.length; x++){
    for (int y = 0; y < Array[x].length ; y++){
        //...
    }
}
return {-1}; //match not found
```

Then, you have to actually print it:

```
int[] position = findValue(Array, find);
System.out.println("Found at " + (position[0] + 1) + "," + (position[1] + 1));
```

---

Part 2: keep asking

Use a `do-while` loop

```
do {
    find = kb.nextInt();
    if (find != -1){
        int[] position = findValue(Array, find);
        //print position, see above
    }
}while (find != -1);
```

OR a simple `while` loop

```
while (find != -1){
    //get input, find value, etc
}
```

Comment: Ah, you answered 2 mins earlier

Comment: Hi, sorry if my question is dumb, I started programming about 2 months ago. What does it mean when you return "-1"?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I can't figure out how to return "-1" if the number that the user asked for is not in the Array..

Use a `for` loop to check if the number matches anything in your array, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array[].length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i][].length; j++){
        if(in != array[i][j]){
            // return -1
        }
    }
}
```

(Of course assuming your integer is `in`)

> Also, I do not know how to keep asking "Please input a number..." and stop when user inputs "-1". Thank you so much for help

Use a `do`/`while` loop, so you can keep doing your stuff *while* your integer doesn't equal -1.

```
do {
    // do your stuff here, while i isn't -1
} while (in != -1);
```

(Again assuming your integer is `in`)

Comment: You're returning `-1` when you find it, not when you don't find it. As for the answering 2 minutes earlier: I know how it feels :P